# Difficulties using seaborn barplot with categorical data

Tags: python, seaborn

I've been encountering a recurrent problem with using seaborn's "categorical" plotting functions to actually plot rates of categorical data.

I crafted a simple example here that I could have sworn used to work with seaborn. I managed to find a workaround using dummy variables, but this isn't always convenient. Does anyone know why my "Version 2" use case for barplot doesn't work?

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate some example data of labels and associated values
outcomes = ['A' for _ in range(50)] + \
           ['B' for _ in range(20)] + \
           ['C' for _ in range(5)] 
trial = range(len(outcomes))

df = DataFrame({'Trial': trial, 'Outcome': outcomes})

plt.close('all')

# Version 1: This works but is a non-ideal workaround

# Generate separate boolean columns for each outcome
df2 = pd.get_dummies(df.Outcome).astype(bool)

plt.figure()
sns.barplot(data=df2, estimator=lambda x: 100 * np.mean(x))
plt.title('Outcomes V1')
plt.ylabel('Percent Trials')
plt.ylim([0,100])
plt.show()

# Version 2: This doesn't work and results in the following error
# unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int' 
plt.figure()
sns.barplot(x='Outcome', data=df, estimator=lambda x: 100 * np.mean(x))
plt.title('Outcomes V2')
plt.ylabel('Percent Trials')
plt.ylim([0,100])
plt.show()
```

[image: Here's what I'm expecting the plot to look like.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the `y` parameter would work for you:

```
sns.barplot(x='Outcome', y='Trial', data=df, estimator=lambda x: 100 * np.mean(x))
```

However, in your case it makes more sense to plot with `sns.countplot` (since you want to treat trial 10 as one occurence, not the actual number ten):

```
sns.countplot(x='Outcome', data=df)
```

Of, if you want percentages, you could do something like:

```
sns.barplot(x='Outcome', y='Trial', data=df, estimator=lambda x: len(x) / len(df) * 100)
```

---

#### Explanation

With a wide form data frame (such as `df2`), you can pass only the data frame to the `data` parameter, and Seaborn will automatically plot each numeric column along the x-axis.

With a long-form data frame (such as `df`), you need to pass arguments to both the `x` and `y` parameters.

From the `sns.barplot` docstring (em added):

> Input data can be passed in a variety of formats, including:
>
> - Vectors of data represented as lists, numpy arrays, or pandas Series
>     objects passed directly to the `x`, `y`, and/or `hue` parameters.
> - **A "long-form" DataFrame, in which case the `x`, `y`, and `hue`
>     variables will determine how the data are plotted.**
> - **A "wide-form" DataFrame, such that each numeric column will be plotted.**
> - Anything accepted by `plt.boxplot` (e.g. a 2d array or list of vectors)